# How to prevent Content from Displaying under div panel

Tags: html, css

Hi I've just made this login panel with `CSS` and `HTML` i used some floats and i ended up with all of content displayed under the panel  i tried `clear: both` but it didn't work , i want all of the other contents to be displayed after the the panel, "not" like what is in the picture.
here is a picture of it:
[image: Login panel]

here is my `HTML` Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mobile Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f99e299e1f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel-container">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="left-text">
            <h1 class="header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
            <h4 class="under-header-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--           -->
        <div class="right-side">
          <div class="right-side-container">
            <h1 class="header2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
            <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="google-login"><div class="login-div" >Login with Google</div></a>
          </br>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-login"><div class="login-div">Login with facebook</div></a>
          </div>
          <h2 class="horizontal-line"><span class="or-text">or</span></h2>
          <form>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password">
          </form>
          <a href="#"><div class="login-button">LOGIN</div></a>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--v v v v Content i want to display under the login panel v v v v v-->
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus doloremque ullam hic earum nostrum magnam, consequuntur ut, nulla, suscipit optio sequi eius. Maxime exercitationem facilis, officia, officiis eligendi error hic voluptatibus asperiores aut, labore possimus? Ad, aperiam consequatur. Qui similique nobis mollitia consequatur laborum provident dolore inventore quia dicta a?</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.panel {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 70vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: url(../images/Endless-Constellation.svg);
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.left-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.right-side-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.header {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
.under-header-text {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.google-login {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
.google-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.login-div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
}
.login-div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.header2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-line {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.or-text {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 239, 239);
}

label {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.login-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(45, 2, 51);
  color: rgb(219, 203, 221);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.login-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(63, 3, 71);
  color: white;
}
.login-button:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
```

is there any solution i should try ?
i tried clear both and used panel:after and clear both page:after... and still it didn't work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's because you're positioning the .panel absolutely... Try to remove position: absolute from .panel class in your CSS file and see if that's what you want

Comment: yes that worked for me the only problem i have now is that the panel is on the top of the page, i solved it by adding margin, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mobile Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f99e299e1f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
 
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.panel {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 70vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 5vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
.left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: url(../images/Endless-Constellation.svg);
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.left-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.right-side-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.header {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
.under-header-text {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.google-login {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
.google-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.login-div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
}
.login-div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.header2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-line {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.or-text {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 239, 239);
}

label {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.login-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(45, 2, 51);
  color: rgb(219, 203, 221);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.login-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(63, 3, 71);
  color: white;
}
.login-button:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="left-text">
            <h1 class="header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
            <h4 class="under-header-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--           -->
        <div class="right-side">
          <div class="right-side-container">
            <h1 class="header2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
            <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="google-login"><div class="login-div" >Login with Google</div></a>
          </br>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-login"><div class="login-div">Login with facebook</div></a>
          </div>
          <h2 class="horizontal-line"><span class="or-text">or</span></h2>
          <form>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password">
          </form>
          <a href="#"><div class="login-button">LOGIN</div></a>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--v v v v Content i want to display under the login panel v v v v v-->
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus doloremque ullam hic earum nostrum magnam, consequuntur ut, nulla, suscipit optio sequi eius. Maxime exercitationem facilis, officia, officiis eligendi error hic voluptatibus asperiores aut, labore possimus? Ad, aperiam consequatur. Qui similique nobis mollitia consequatur laborum provident dolore inventore quia dicta a?</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your code or per say end result was victim of positioning rules. most specifically for **.panel** class. from design view you did not need position on the element since it would have been the very first item of its parent. Because you applied **position:absolute** it broke out of what normal flow page painting was following. Thus, the div you needed at the bottom went on top since panel was on its own flow.

I could see the motivation for position on panel to get **5vh** margin from top or what ever. but that could have been achieved just as easily through **margin-top: 5vh;*.

my intervention;

1. changed position:absolute to position:relative
2. added margin-bottom:10vh to give little curtain space at the bottom.

EXAMPLE with NO POSITIONING

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mobile Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f99e299e1f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;

}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.panel {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 70vw;

  margin-top: 5vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
.left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: url(../images/Endless-Constellation.svg);
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.left-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.right-side-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.header {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
.under-header-text {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.google-login {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
.google-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.login-div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
}
.login-div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08),
    0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.header2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-line {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.or-text {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 239, 239);
}

label {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.login-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(45, 2, 51);
  color: rgb(219, 203, 221);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.login-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(63, 3, 71);
  color: white;
}
.login-button:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="left-text">
            <h1 class="header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
            <h4 class="under-header-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--           -->
        <div class="right-side">
          <div class="right-side-container">
            <h1 class="header2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
            <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="google-login"><div class="login-div" >Login with Google</div></a>
          </br>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-login"><div class="login-div">Login with facebook</div></a>
          </div>
          <h2 class="horizontal-line"><span class="or-text">or</span></h2>
          <form>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password">
          </form>
          <a href="#"><div class="login-button">LOGIN</div></a>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--v v v v Content i want to display under the login panel v v v v v-->
    <div class="under"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus doloremque ullam hic earum nostrum magnam, consequuntur ut, nulla, suscipit optio sequi eius. Maxime exercitationem facilis, officia, officiis eligendi error hic voluptatibus asperiores aut, labore possimus? Ad, aperiam consequatur. Qui similique nobis mollitia consequatur laborum provident dolore inventore quia dicta a?</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, The problem is solved now, Turns out i had to use margin-top instead.

Comment: @Anas CHAHID welcome. It was one of the gotchas I had to learn the hard way when learning responsive design. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp 
An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Comment: one workaround which is hacky is to make parent element position:relative then add position:absolute to child, other wise it would run to body tag. That is what happened in your case since page class did not have any positioning applied on to it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `position: absolute;` from the `.panel`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 70vw;
  top: 5vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.left-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.right-side-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.header {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.under-header-text {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.google-login {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.google-login:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.login-div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

.login-div {
  height: 2.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 2px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-line {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.or-text {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 239, 239);
}

label {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.login-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: rgb(45, 2, 51);
  color: rgb(219, 203, 221);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.login-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(63, 3, 71);
  color: white;
}

.login-button:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="left-side">
      <div class="left-text">
        <h1 class="header">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
        <h4 class="under-header-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--           -->
    <div class="right-side">
      <div class="right-side-container">
        <h1 class="header2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
        <div class="login">
          <a href="#" class="google-login">
            <div class="login-div">Login with Google</div>
          </a>
          </br>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-login">
            <div class="login-div">Login with facebook</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="horizontal-line"><span class="or-text">or</span></h2>
        <form>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text">
          <br>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password">
        </form>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="login-button">LOGIN</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--v v v v Content i want to display under the login panel v v v v v-->
<div">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus doloremque ullam hic earum nostrum magnam, consequuntur ut, nulla, suscipit optio sequi eius. Maxime exercitationem facilis, officia, officiis eligendi error hic voluptatibus asperiores
    aut, labore possimus? Ad, aperiam consequatur. Qui similique nobis mollitia consequatur laborum provident dolore inventore quia dicta a?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question, i meant that i don't want the text to be displayed on the top of the page, i wanted to place the text after the login panel. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: @AnasCHAHID You need to remove `position: absolute;` from `.panel`